# Sudoku - checking if there are duplicates in rows&columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, for-loop, nested-loops

So my goal is to write a programme that extracts non-zero integers from each row and column and checks if there are any repeated values, and return False if duplicates exist, else return True.
It's working fine for rows, but I'm struggling to obtain the non-zero entries in each column. I can only get non-zero entries from one specific column, but I don't know how to iterate through all columns and check for duplicates.
I've tried using nested for loops, but it doesn't seem to work because it would just return a list of all non-zero integers from each list in L.

```
    def sudoku(L):
    #checks the rows
    
    for i in L:
        row=[x for x in i if x != 0]
        for j in row:
            if row.count(j)!=1:
                return False

    #checks the columns
    col=list()
    for x in range(9):
        if L[x][0]!=0:
            col.append(L[x][0])
    print(col)

L = [[5,3,0,0,7,0,0,0,0],
     [6,0,0,1,9,5,0,0,0],
     [0,9,8,0,0,0,0,6,0],
     [8,0,0,0,6,0,0,0,3],
     [4,0,0,8,0,3,0,0,1],
     [7,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,6],
     [0,6,0,0,0,0,2,8,0],
     [0,0,0,4,1,9,0,0,5],
     [0,0,0,0,8,0,0,7,9]]

print(sudoku(L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    column = [[x[count] for x in L if x[count] != 0] for count in range(9) ]
    for c in column:
        if len(set(c)) != len(c):
            return False
        else:
            return True
```

`set()` removes any duplicates

The code can be shortened to

```
    column = [[x[count] for x in L if x[count] != 0] for count in range(9) ]
    return False not in [True if len(set(c)) == len(c) else False for c in column]
```

Comment: Hmm I think there's a problem - len(set(c))==len(c) has to be satisfied for ALL c in column, I think changing to this will work: if all(len(set(c)) == len(c) for c in col):
        return True
    else:
        return False

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: you want the condition for each column separately?, i initially though you wanted it be if one column has duplicates then return false for everything

Comment: Oh I wanted the code to return True if all non-zero columns have no duplicates, so I think we need to use the all() function to check all columns. I think the for loop in your code will be terminated once it finds ONE column whose len(set())==len(). But anyway you've helped me out so much Thank you!

Comment: will adjust my answer

Comment: but if one column has duplicates don't you want it to return false?

Comment: Yes but the for loop you've written will go through each c in column and will terminate the loop if one element of column satisfies the if statement, but the rest of the lists in column might contain duplicates, so I think adding the all() function will resolve this :)

Comment: I see now, i've swapped the conditions around, it should work now

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be to convert the same index for every column to a row, and reuse the code for the rows

```
L = [[5,3,0,0,7,0,0,0,0],
     [6,0,0,1,9,5,0,0,0],
     [0,9,8,0,0,0,0,6,0],
     [8,0,0,0,6,0,0,0,3],
     [4,0,0,8,0,3,0,0,1],
     [7,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,6],
     [0,6,0,0,0,0,2,8,0],
     [0,0,0,4,1,9,0,0,5],
     [0,0,0,0,8,0,0,7,9]]

columns = []

for i in range(len(L)):
  columns.append([])
  for row in L:
    if row[i] != 0:
      columns[i].append(row[i])

print(columns) #List of columns with no 0’s
```